# running multiple services(IoT) with python flask

Tags: python, flask, microservices, mqtt

How can I initiate an mqqt service and run it parallel to flask application in the application context. The flask application serves as its web client and the two processes needs to run parallel. Another option from module initialization or the best module that I can use. I commented out to let the web app run as a standalone app and also started mqtt as a standalone service

```
    #Klient=Mqtt(myapp)
#The application factory
def create_app(settings="config.py"):
    """Factory function to start the web app when everthing(i.e configurations are set up in place.)"""
    myapp=Flask(__name__)#Creating app instance
    #...more configuration codes are here...
    myapp.config['SQLALCHEMY_POOL_RECYCLE'] = 299
    myapp.config['SQLALCHEMY_POOL_TIMEOUT'] = 20
    myapp.config['MQTT_BROKER_URL']='broker.hivemq.com'
    myapp.config['MQTT_BROKER_PORT']=1883
    myapp.config['MQTT_USERNAME']=''
    myapp.config['MQTT_PASSWORD']=''
    myapp.config['MQTT_KEEPALIVE']=5
    myapp.config['MQTT_TLS_ENABLED']=False
    DEBUG=False


    """Initializing extensions"""
    db.init_app(myapp)
    

    from models import User, Book
    with myapp.app_context():
        db.create_all()
        db.session.commit()

      
    socketio.init_app(myapp)
    admin.init_app(myapp)#The administrators instance
    encrypt.init_app(myapp)#Instance of bcrypt password hashing utility
    #client.on_connect=on_connect
    #client.on_message=on_message
    #client.connect('broker.hivemq.com', 1883)
    #client.loop_forever()

    


    #Registering routes
    myapp.register_blueprint(routes)
    myapp.register_blueprint(admin_bp)


    #Managing logins
    login_manager = LoginManager()
    login_manager.login_view = 'routes.login'
    login_manager.init_app(myapp)

    @login_manager.user_loader
    def load_user(id):
        return User.query.get(int(id))

    return myapp.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I would start services separatelly. And if you have to start in one script then they may need to run in separated threads/processes.